# missing 1 required positional argument: 'message' Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Код ниже

```
from telebot import types 
import config
number=['0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Бомбер")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}! Я тестовый бот.Что будем делать? :)".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
        if(message.text == "Бомбер"):
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Кому будем ставить? :)")
                back = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
                markup.add(back)
                save_number1()
            
        elif (message.text == "Вернуться в главное меню"):
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Бомбер")
            markup.add(button1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в главное меню", reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="На такую комманду я не запрограммировал..")
def save_number1(message):
    print("pereshli")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите номер пользователя", reply_markup=markup)
    txt = message.text
    print(txt)
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Выводит ошибку : save_number1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Answer (score 0):

При вызове функции **save_number1** вы должны задать аргумент **message**, так как в функции **save_number1** у вас стоит параметр **message**

```
save_number1(message)
```